# How to update prompt on directory change

Tags: zsh, prompt

For example with following:

```
prompt_git() {
  local PL_BRANCH_CHAR
  () {
    PL_BRANCH_CHAR='!'
  }
  local ref mode repo_path
  repo_path=$(git rev-parse --git-dir 2>/dev/null)

  if $(git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree >/dev/null 2>&1); then
    ref=$(git symbolic-ref HEAD 2> /dev/null) || ref="➦ $(git rev-parse --short HEAD 2> /dev/null)"

    if [[ -e "${repo_path}/BISECT_LOG" ]]; then
      mode=" <B>"
    elif [[ -e "${repo_path}/MERGE_HEAD" ]]; then
      mode=" >M<"
    elif [[ -e "${repo_path}/rebase" || -e "${repo_path}/rebase-apply" || -e "${repo_path}/rebase-merge" || -e "${repo_path}/../.dotest" ]]; then
      mode=" >R>"
    fi

    setopt promptsubst
    autoload -Uz vcs_info

    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' enable git
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' get-revision true
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' check-for-changes true
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' stagedstr '✚'
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' unstagedstr '●'
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' formats ' %u%c'
    zstyle ':vcs_info:*' actionformats ' %u%c'
    vcs_info
    echo -n "${ref/refs\/heads\//$PL_BRANCH_CHAR }${vcs_info_msg_0_%% }${mode} "
  fi
}

build_prompt() {
  RETVAL=$?
  prompt_git
}

PROMPT="%{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)"
```

it doesn't react if I change directory

To update git stats I need to `exec "${SHELL}" "$@"`

How to react on directory change automatically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with `PROMPT="…$(build_prompt)"`, you're running `build_prompt` at the time of the assignment, i.e. when your `.zshrc` is read, and using the result of that one run as the prompt.

To run `build_prompt` each time the prompt is displayed, include the string `$(build_prompt)` directly in the value of the `PROMPT` variable. This requires turning on the `prompt_subst` option.

```
setopt prompt_subst
PROMPT='%{%f%b%k%}$(build_prompt)'
```

Alternatively, run the prompt-setting code in a [`precmd` hook](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-precmd).

```
set_prompt () {
  …
  PROMPT="%{%f%b%k%}${ref/refs\/heads\//$PL_BRANCH_CHAR }${vcs_info_msg_0_%% }${mode} "
  fi
}
precmd_functions+=set_prompt
set_prompt
```

Also note that the code that runs `setopt`, `zstyle` and `autoload` doesn't belong in a function. It kind of works but it'll prevent from changing these settings later. This is code that needs to run only once, so put it in your `.zshrc` outside of any function.

To answer the question you asked, to run code on a directory change, put it in a [`chpwd` hook](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Functions.html#index-chpwd). But this isn't what you want: you need to update the prompt not only on a directory change but also on a git state change, so the update code needs to run every time the prompt is displayed.

Comment: strange but `setopt prompt_subst` doesn't work

Comment: [[ -z $precmd_functions ]] && precmd_functions=()
precmd_functions=($precmd_functions prompt) - works

Comment: In the `prompt_subst` version, you have to enclose the prompt string in single quotes. Otherwise the substitution will be done at the time PROMPT has been assigned. In addition, the `setopt` is unnecessary, because `prompt_subst` is turned on by default.